# Trace all the calls (+ their stack) made to a WCF service

Tags: wcf, performance, logging

I have a WCF Service which is currently in Production. The code performance are not where we would like them to be and we are unable to reproduce in our Staging environment.

I was wondering if it is possible to log every single method call made to the service and by the service. Essentially I would like a sequential list of all the calls and time stamps (our code isn't multi-threaded).

Is there a way to achieve that without having to instrument the binaries. Is there a level of tracing under the system.diagnostic node in the web.config that we could change?

Comment: This sounds like you need to profile your service. In that case, I don't see how the stack traces will help you.

Comment: Is there a utility like *jstack* or *pstack* or *lsstack*? An exhaustive set of function call traces will leave you guessing what's responsible for the most time. A moderate-size set of stack traces taken at random times will give you a good idea of what's taking time, because the larger the fraction of time something takes, the more samples will catch it. It can be surprising how few stack samples you need before you get a really clear picture of what's taking time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you configured tracing in your configuration file? [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx) is a good article on the subject.

Here is a sample configuration you can use and modify for your needs:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="ServiceModel"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData="C:\ServiceModel.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
                <add name="MessageLogging"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData="C:\MessageLogging.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="True"
                        logMalformedMessages="False"
                        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="True"
                        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="False"
                        maxMessagesToLog="10000"
                        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="10000" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Use the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) (SvcTraceViewer.exe) to view the resulting logs.

Answer (score 2):

Check [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and optionally also [WCF message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) and use [SvcTraceViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to check collected data - you can alternatively build your trace listener for logging traces for example to database. WCF also provides [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx).